# Distribution model with varying probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was curious about whether there are any distributions that can model a varying probability.
To illustrate this, I came up with a hypothetical question:

**The Problem:**

There is a hypothetical coin (with only two outcomes) with the initial probability of getting a tail (denoted as $p, 0\lt p \lt 1$). You start with an initial sum of €$0$.

Every time you get a tail, you lose €$1$, and $p$ increases by $.01$.

Every time you get a head, you gain €$1$, and $p$ decreases by $.01$.

How much money can you expect to have after flipping the coin an infinite number of times?

**What I've Tried:**

I tried running the following Python code to simulate the coin flips:

```
import random as rand

p = .5
s = 0
def flip(p):
    x = float(rand.uniform(0,1))
    if (x>=p):
        return True
    else:
        return False
n = int(input("n:"))
for a in range(0,n):
    if (flip(p)):
        s+=1
        if (p < .99):
            p += .01
    else:
        s-=1
        if (p > .01):
            p -= .01
print("Final sum: ", str(s))
```

I tried multiple runs of $n = 10^{15}$, but I am getting different sums for every run.

**Existing Knowledge:**

I am a high-school student, so I know the basics of probability and probability distributions (Bayes Theorem, Normal PD, Normal CD, Binomial PD, Binomial CD)

Comment: Excellent question for a high school student

Comment: Based on your code, you assume that if $p$ reaches either $0$ or $1$, its value no longer changes.  I guess once that barrier is reached, you stop tossing the coin. 

Not $100%$ sure about what follows. Given an infinite number of tosses, $p$ is sure to reach either $0$ or $1$, whichever happens first (and both events are equally likely). So the question is what is the expected number of coin tosses before reaching either value.

Comment: I will try again by changing the limits to .99 and .01 respectively. Thanks for pointing that out. Edit: Well, final sum still keeps changing every run.

Comment: Following @Patricio's comment, if you do allow p to reach 0 or 1, then you will either win infinite money or lose infinite money and so the expected value is undefined. If p does cap out at .99, then your money is likely to oscillate between large positive numbers and large negative numbers infinitely many times, so even "return at infinity" will be undefined.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.

Comment: @SaumyaShah Regarding the other question you asked (it is rightfully deleted because it is off-topic, I think the right place to ask is [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/) or [chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com)), I think you should perhaps join some special (university) courses for talented high school students, and ask the instructors there. AFAIK, mathematicians are very busy with their research.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion! Will look into them.